# Compile apk using only android phone

Tags: android, compiler-construction, apk

I would like to build a simple apk compiler that runs on android. The objective is to compile some java/android app source code within android.

I searched a lot on Internet but could not find something that could help me with this.

Any of you knows if this is possible? I know AIDE, but I wanted to see how the process of compiling and apk on Android Phone works.

Comment: compiler means you compile it to machine code, but you can simply re-create eclipse for android ha-ha

Comment: That's true. I can't re-create eclipse, but I do not want to create a IDE for android. I just wanted to know what is necessary to create a simple app builder for android.

Comment: There are online app creators I think, just take one as a sample or make something simpler for phone and you are done!

Comment: But this is exactly what I need! What commands or libs that I have to use to build apk from an Android.

Comment: I think this https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html